# Kaplan Meier with R

Tags: r

Im a newbie with R, so i have some Problems with the confidence intervals. Here ist my code:

```
    library(survival)
    zeiten <- c(7, 3, 24, 19, 8, 7, 11, 19)
    delta <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
    survivalobjekt <- Surv(zeiten, delta)
    km1 <- survfit(survivalobjekt ~ 1)
    plot(x=km1, col=c("black", "red", "red"), xlab="x", ylab="S(x)", lty=1)
```

so now we check the summary of km1:

```
    Call: survfit(formula = survivalobjekt ~ 1)

    time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
    3      8       1    0.875   0.117        0.673        1.000
    7      7       2    0.625   0.171        0.365        1.000
    8      5       1    0.500   0.177        0.250        1.000
   19      3       1    0.333   0.180        0.116        0.961
   24      1       1    0.000     NaN           NA           NA
```

The problems are these NA at the end. when i use plot(km1), I get 
[image: 1], 
but i want to get 
[image: 2] 
How can i get it? How can i remove those NA´s?

Comment: What do you want to have instead of the NAs?

Comment: Just want to have the confidence intervals till end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot Kaplan-Meier usin `ggplot2`.
Confidence intervals are plotted according to your needs.

```
library(ggfortify)
library(survival)
zeiten <- c(7, 3, 24, 19, 8, 7, 11, 19)
delta <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
km1 <- survfit(Surv(zeiten, delta) ~ 1)
autoplot(km1, censor.shape = '*', censor.size = 5,
        surv.colour = 'darkorange', conf.int.fill = 'orange',
        surv.size = 1, censor.colour = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Marco! But i get 2 errors:                                     
 Warnmeldungen:
1: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_text).

Comment: And my plot is not like yours :(

Comment: @H.Down My code runs with no errors or warnings and my plot is exactly equal to the plot that you want to get ! Can you post the code that you are trying to run ? You changed my code and I suspect that you are making some errors.

Comment: @H.Down I suspect that you changed my code and you are now using `autoplot` of  `survMisc` ! Is it true ?

Comment: Done. Can you please tell me, how can i insert Legend in the plot? Like: Redline is the observe data; Orange space the 95% confidence intervals. Thank you!